# How to fix error Macro not expanded: proc macro crate is missing dylib

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

Somebody knows how to get rid of the error "Macro .... not expanded: proc macro crate is missing dylib"?

[image]

I am getting that error on pretty much every anchor macro since I have installed the newest version of Anchor and Rust compiler.

I am using:

- Anchor `0.28.0`
- Rustc `1.70.0`
- Rust-analyzer (VS Extension) `0.3.1566`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, I just had to solve a rust-analyzer conflict in one of the folders of my project's workspace in VS Code. Seems like it was crashing before being able to expand the macros.